# Запись данных из скрипта в гугл-таблицу

Tags: node.js, google-spreadsheet

Мне нужно записать из Node.js некоторые данные в гугл-таблицу.

Все взаимодействие с ней у меня реализуется следующим образом:

**На самом деле, для ответа, читать весь этот код не обязательно - я его добавил на всякий случай, вдруг ошибка у меня не в том куске, в котором я предполагаю**

Есть 3 файла:

- `index.js` (основной файл)
- `sheet.js` (с описанием метода для записи данных)
- `sconfig.js` (авторизация)

Код каждого файла:

**index.js**

```
const readline = require('readline')
const {google} = require('googleapis')
const sheets = require('./sheet')

sheets.append(
    "Sheet1!A1",
    [
        ["data 1", "data 2", "data3"]
    ]
);
```

**sheet.js**

```
const fs = require('fs')
const {authorize, google} = require('./sconfig');

// Change it with your id.
const spreadsheetId = "ид таблицы";

const append = (range, values) => {
    fs.readFile('client_secret.json', (err, content) => {
        if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
        // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Sheets API.
        authorize(JSON.parse(content), (auth) => {
            const sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth });
            const valueInputOption = 'USER_ENTERED';
            const resource = {values};
            sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
                spreadsheetId, range, valueInputOption, resource
            }, (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log("Success!");
                }
            });
        });
    });
}

module.exports = {
    append
};
```

**sconfig.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const OAuth2Client = google.auth.OAuth2;
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'];
const TOKEN_PATH = 'credentials.json';

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
const authorize = function (credentials, callback) {
    const { client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris } = credentials.installed;
    const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2Client(client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

    // Check if we have previously stored a token.
    fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
        if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
        oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
        callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
 */
const getNewToken = function (oAuth2Client, callback) {
    const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type: 'offline',
        scope: SCOPES,
    });
    console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout,
    });
    rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
        rl.close();
        oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
            if (err) return callback(err);
            oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
            // Store the token to disk for later program executions
            fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
                if (err) console.error(err);
                console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
            });
            callback(oAuth2Client);
        });
    });
}

module.exports = {
    authorize,
    google
};
```

Авторизация проходит успешно (ну я так думаю, потому что ошибка которая приходит забивает всю консоль и ее начало я не вижу).

Вот полное содержание консоли после запуска этого кода:

```
        aborted: [Function],
        error: [Function],
        timeout: [Function],
        prefinish: [Function: requestOnPrefinish] },
     _eventsCount: 6,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     output: [],
     outputEncodings: [],
     outputCallbacks: [],
     outputSize: 0,
     writable: true,
     _last: true,
     upgrading: false,
     chunkedEncoding: false,
     shouldKeepAlive: false,
     useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
     sendDate: false,
     _removedConnection: false,
     _removedContLen: false,
     _removedTE: false,
     _contentLength: null,
     _hasBody: true,
     _trailer: '',
     finished: true,
     _headerSent: true,
     socket:
      TLSSocket {
        _tlsOptions: [Object],
        _secureEstablished: true,
        _securePending: false,
        _newSessionPending: false,
        _controlReleased: true,
        _SNICallback: null,
        servername: null,
        npnProtocol: false,
        alpnProtocol: false,
        authorized: true,
        authorizationError: null,
        encrypted: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 10,
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: null,
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'sheets.googleapis.com',
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: false,
        domain: null,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _bytesDispatched: 529,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: undefined,
        _server: null,
        ssl: null,
        _requestCert: true,
        _rejectUnauthorized: true,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true,
        write: [Function: writeAfterFIN],
        _idleNext: null,
        _idlePrev: null,
        _idleTimeout: -1,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 52,
        [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 738 },
     connection:
      TLSSocket {
        _tlsOptions: [Object],
        _secureEstablished: true,
        _securePending: false,
        _newSessionPending: false,
        _controlReleased: true,
        _SNICallback: null,
        servername: null,
        npnProtocol: false,
        alpnProtocol: false,
        authorized: true,
        authorizationError: null,
        encrypted: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 10,
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: null,
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'sheets.googleapis.com',
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: false,
        domain: null,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _bytesDispatched: 529,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: undefined,
        _server: null,
        ssl: null,
        _requestCert: true,
        _rejectUnauthorized: true,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true,
        write: [Function: writeAfterFIN],
        _idleNext: null,
        _idlePrev: null,
        _idleTimeout: -1,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 52,
        [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 738 },
     _header: 'POST /v4/spreadsheets/1THbsLQ-t9wfFaf5uUCTlYRxy_jAgaoX7WsjhbLkIsu
A/values/Sheet1!A1:append?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: appl
ication/json, text/plain, */*\r\nContent-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8\r\
nAuthorization: Bearer ya29.Gly-BdDwgvQpW1zPbtjabyoxod30-5BOmYLhe6qPMaE_IDQ7yMQz
v0OnIMMMv8dmm4H7vo4nIcJOHS8QRlpxSKZDYW5BdBh8qNcOqSwLt3OmKxQWMOQxpCYEmzGf3g\r\nUs
er-Agent: google-api-nodejs-client/1.4.0\r\nContent-Length: 40\r\nHost: sheets.g
oogleapis.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
     _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
     agent:
      Agent {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        defaultPort: 443,
        protocol: 'https:',
        options: [Object],
        requests: {},
        sockets: [Object],
        freeSockets: {},
        keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
        keepAlive: false,
        maxSockets: Infinity,
        maxFreeSockets: 256,
        maxCachedSessions: 100,
        _sessionCache: [Object] },
     socketPath: undefined,
     timeout: undefined,
     method: 'POST',
     path: '/v4/spreadsheets/1THbsLQ-t9wfFaf5uUCTlYRxy_jAgaoX7WsjhbLkIsuA/values
/Sheet1!A1:append?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED',
     _ended: true,
     res:
      IncomingMessage {
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: false,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 3,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        socket: [Object],
        connection: [Object],
        httpVersionMajor: 1,
        httpVersionMinor: 1,
        httpVersion: '1.1',
        complete: true,
        headers: [Object],
        rawHeaders: [Array],
        trailers: {},
        rawTrailers: [],
        upgrade: false,
        url: '',
        method: null,
        statusCode: 400,
        statusMessage: 'Bad Request',
        client: [Object],
        _consuming: true,
        _dumped: false,
        req: [Circular],
        responseUrl: 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1THbsLQ-t9wf
Faf5uUCTlYRxy_jAgaoX7WsjhbLkIsuA/values/Sheet1!A1:append?valueInputOption=USER_E
NTERED',
        read: [Function] },
     aborted: undefined,
     timeoutCb: null,
     upgradeOrConnect: false,
     parser: null,
     maxHeadersCount: null,
     _redirectable:
      Writable {
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _options: [Object],
        _redirectCount: 0,
        _requestBodyLength: 40,
        _requestBodyBuffers: [],
        _onNativeResponse: [Function],
        _currentRequest: [Circular],
        _currentUrl: 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1THbsLQ-t9wf
Faf5uUCTlYRxy_jAgaoX7WsjhbLkIsuA/values/Sheet1!A1:append?valueInputOption=USER_E
NTERED' },
     [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]:
      { accept: [Array],
        'content-type': [Array],
        authorization: [Array],
        'user-agent': [Array],
        'content-length': [Array],
        host: [Array] } },
  response:
   { status: 400,
     statusText: 'Bad Request',
     headers:
      { vary: 'X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding',
        'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        date: 'Thu, 17 May 2018 09:27:52 GMT',
        server: 'ESF',
        'cache-control': 'private',
        'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
        'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
        'alt-svc': 'hq=":443"; ma=2592000; quic=51303433; quic=51303432; quic=51
303431; quic=51303339; quic=51303335,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="43,42,41,39,35"
',
        'accept-ranges': 'none',
        connection: 'close' },
     config:
      { adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
        transformRequest: [Object],
        transformResponse: [Object],
        timeout: 0,
        xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
        xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
        maxContentLength: 2147483648,
        validateStatus: [Function],
        headers: [Object],
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1THbsLQ-t9wfFaf5uUCT
lYRxy_jAgaoX7WsjhbLkIsuA/values/Sheet1!A1:append',
        paramsSerializer: [Function],
        data: '{"values":[["data 1","data 2","data3"]]}',
        params: [Object] },
     request:
      ClientRequest {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 6,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: true,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: false,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: false,
        _removedConnection: false,
        _removedContLen: false,
        _removedTE: false,
        _contentLength: null,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: [Object],
        connection: [Object],
        _header: 'POST /v4/spreadsheets/1THbsLQ-t9wfFaf5uUCTlYRxy_jAgaoX7WsjhbLk
IsuA/values/Sheet1!A1:append?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: a
pplication/json, text/plain, */*\r\nContent-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
\r\nAuthorization: Bearer ya29.Gly-BdDwgvQpW1zPbtjabyoxod30-5BOmYLhe6qPMaE_IDQ7y
MQzv0OnIMMMv8dmm4H7vo4nIcJOHS8QRlpxSKZDYW5BdBh8qNcOqSwLt3OmKxQWMOQxpCYEmzGf3g\r\
nUser-Agent: google-api-nodejs-client/1.4.0\r\nContent-Length: 40\r\nHost: sheet
s.googleapis.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
        _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
        agent: [Object],
        socketPath: undefined,
        timeout: undefined,
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/v4/spreadsheets/1THbsLQ-t9wfFaf5uUCTlYRxy_jAgaoX7WsjhbLkIsuA/val
ues/Sheet1!A1:append?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED',
        _ended: true,
        res: [Object],
        aborted: undefined,
        timeoutCb: null,
        upgradeOrConnect: false,
        parser: null,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        _redirectable: [Object],
        [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object] },
     data: { error: [Object] } },
  code: 400,
  errors:
   [ { message: 'Unable to parse range: Sheet1!A1',
       domain: 'global',
       reason: 'badRequest' } ] }
```

Я не понимаю, что оно от меня хочет но думаю, что как-то неправильно обращаюсь к столбцу вот тут:

```
sheets.append(
    "Sheet1!A1",
    [
        ["data 1", "data 2", "data3"]
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в имени листа. Код копировался с англоязычного сайта, и там видимо по дефолту первый лист таблицы называется `Sheet1` . Но поскольку я работал с русскоязычными таблицами - у меня лист назывался `Лист1`.

Помогло переименование листа в `List1` и обращение к нему вот так:

```
sheets.append(
    "List1!A1",
    [
        ["data 1", "data 2", "data3"]
    ]
);
```